# Is inconsistent charging bad for batteries?

Tags: battery-charging

I am designing a generator for a bench press that generates electricity when you work out, but it would charge the battery inconsistently and I don't know if that would be bad for a battery.

Comment: To some extent the answer depends on the battery chemistry you use, and what you plan on doing with the charge in the battery. You need to share more detail.

Comment: Note that you will expend power, not generate it, if you use electricity to simulate gravity.  You can make a useful exercise machine where you have to push upwards with force equivalent to what would lift a certain weight to generate power as the bar moved upwards, but when it stops moving you will feel only the weight of the real bar, not the simulated one, so you will lose almost all of the benefit of the muscle control part of the exercise but safety will be greatly increased.  Obviously a mechanism to pull the bar down capable of pulling equivalent to many kg would be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

For most cell chemistries, *deep* discharge, *overcharge*, or *very rapid* (high current) charge or discharge are damaging. Simply irregular use, as long as it **does not completely deplete the battery** during disuse, is harmless.

If you use a charge regulator designed for the battery, there should be no harm in inconsistent charging -- in fact, some chemistries *benefit* from occasional charge/discharge, rather than floating at full potential.